# get twitter feed (R or python)

Tags: python, json, r, twitter

I used to get twitter data using R with an xml package. Seems like they no longer use xmls and only use json. I tried a few methodologies with json and I keep getting an error saying API 1.0 not available anymore and I need to use API 1.1. Fine but there seems to be no clear documentation in how to.

Can someone guide me to a location or provide sample code for getting twitter data.

I used to do this in R but seems like python is better for this. If someone can provide a guide in either or both would be very much appreciated.(or some sample code with explanation)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [sixohsix's `twitter` library for Python](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter).

There is some documentation on the github page, and if you're familiar with at least a bit of Python (I didn't know Python very well when I started using it), then it's pretty easy to use. It supports API v1.1 (v1.0 is deprecated and doesn't even work anymore, afaik).

With some Python scripts on a Ubuntu netbook I was able to continuously query the API for almost a year now, without one crash. I wouldn't recommend R for this, especially if you're after a lot of data.

You can still use R for data analysis, you can actually plug it into your Python scripts directly using [`rpy2`](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html).

Answer (score 0):

This package might be useful.  It was just released a few days ago.

[twitteR package for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf)

Comment: I am looking at this package but having problems with PIN. I go to the link and enter the pin and get: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer. I tried as is single quote and double quote. Any ideas

Comment: Could you be more specific about what data you want from Twitter and where you are getting hung up?  Code examples would be great, then maybe "we" can duplicate what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API was updated from version 1.0 to version 1.1. Many codes are now defunct since authentication is needed. Many blog posts with code samples are no longer valid.

For Python, I prefer the [bear's package](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/README.md).

For R, I think the standard package is [twitteR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html).

Whatever you do, you'll have to authenticate your "application" as a developer: [link](https://dev.twitter.com/).